# Change CSS at WooCommere checkout page for specific product

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I created a WooCommerce checkout page using Elementor to customize its look and feel. At the top there is a section with class `.elementor-widget-icon-list` above the checkout fields that reads: Luego de abonar...

I would like to apply the CSS property display: none at the checkout page to the class `.elementor-widget-icon-list` only if the product ID is `1813`.

To see what I mean, you can go to the following link and click on Comprar at the bottom, you'll be redirected to the checkout page I am talking about: https://aefcoaching.com/gimnasio-mental-comprar/

So, can this be done? If so, how? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

put this in your theme in the file :

function.php

```
global $woocommerce;
      
    $productID = wc_get_order( $order_id );
      
    if ( $productID ) {
    if ($productID == 1813){
    echo "<style> .elementor-widget-container { display: none !important ; } <style>"
    }
```

Comment: hey, this code gives me Syntax Error: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '<' in your code on line 7

Answer (score -1):

You can achieve it using the **functions.php** file in the **child theme**. There are many ways and I think the most efficient one would be to create a **hook** for a specific page and add jQuery or CSS there. It looks like this (JavaScript aproach):

Code for **functions.php** file

```
  function my_super_hook() {
    if ( is_single(1813) && is_product() ) {
     wp_enqueue_script('custom', get_stylesheet_directory_uri().'/scripts/custom.js');
    }
}



add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_super_hook' );
```

In your custom.js use JavaScript to set

```
$(".elementor-widget-icon-list").css("display", "none");
```

Of course, you can import a CSS file instead of js if you want.

Comment: hey, I tried doing this with a CSS file I uploaded to https://aefcoaching.com/customCSS/gimnasioMental.css, but it's not working. The code is:
```function my_super_hook() {
   if ( is_single(1813) && is_product(1813) ) {
     wp_enqueue_script('custom', get_stylesheet_directory_uri().'/customCSS/gimnasioMental.css');
    }
}



add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_super_hook' );```

Comment: Hi. Did you make a child theme? I suggest you to use .js file first just to test path. Create one and inside just put console.log("hello');, that is how you test your hook. you must set up the correct path in the child theme, then just check console to see Hello message. Once you see it that's it, your file is included.

Comment: Or try this code from another answer. echo "<style> .elementor-widget-container { display: none !important ; } <style>";